# Howto set cookie_httponly?

Tags: php, symfony, httpcookie

So i have my code where i use session

```
$session->start();
if (...){
...
$session->set('session', $someVar);
}
```

And Ive got some problem when i try in console document.cookie. How can i set cookie_httponly, im using symfony. And where should i set it? i tried to set it in the same file where i used $session->start();

```
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1);
class Class 
{
$session->start();
if (...){
...
$session->set('session', $someVar);
}
}
```

Was it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set PHP.ini values then set session cookie parameters before you start session.

```
ini_set("session.cookie_domain",".".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
ini_set("session.cookie_secure",true);
ini_set("session.cookie_httponly",true);

session_set_cookie_params(
    0, 
    "/", 
    ini_get("session.cookie_domain"),
    ini_get("session.cookie_secure"),
    ini_get("session.cookie_httponly")
); 

session_start();
```

To set cookie:

```
setCookie(
    $cookie_name="CookieName",
    $cookie_value="CookieValue",
    $cookie_lifetime=time()+31536000, // 1 Year
    $cookie_path="/",
    ini_get("session.cookie_domain"),
    ini_get("session.cookie_secure"),
    ini_get("session.cookie_httponly")
)
```

Refer to the official PHP Manual for more details.